# How to pass type information through templates to instantiate objects within in D

Tags: multithreading, templates, d

How would one pass type information into a thread, so objects of the correct types could be created in the thread using the passed info? Something like this:

```
struct Test // or class Test
{
  int x, y, z;
}

void testInThread(F, T ...)(T args)
{
  auto obj = F(args);
  // Do stuf with obj in the new thread
}

auto tid = std.concurrency.spawn!(testInThread, Test, 1, 2, 3);

// Threads and stuff...
```

This doesn't compile, but I'm sure something like this should be possible. I think there's just something I'm not understanding about template parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line here would compile:

```
    auto tid = std.concurrency.spawn(&testInThread!(Test, int, int, int), 1, 2, 3);
```

I'm not sure if you can make it prettier with implicit deduction of those ints or not though. But the reason this compiles is that `spawn` expects a function. `testInThread` is a template that generates a function. If you pass it the compile time argument list over there without a runtime list, you can get the address to the function... which is good enough for `spawn`.

Answer (score 4):

`spawn` accepts a pointer to a function. What you're trying to pass it is a template for a function. If you want to pass it a templated function, that templated function must be fully instantiated - in this case something like

```
auto tid = std.concurrency.spawn(&testInThread!(Test, int ,int, int), 1, 2, 3);
```

But as templates are compile time constructs, it's not going to work to pass template arguments across threads and have a template instantiated on the other side. All templates much be instantiated at compile time. So, if the issue is really that you want to be able to pass a templated function to `spawn` and have it be called in the other thread, then the example above does that, but if you really want to be passing template arguments across threads, then you're out of luck.

You might want to read the [template chapter](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/templates.html) from Ali Çehreli's [online book on D](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/) in order to better understand templates.